# Android Eclipse changing text on a snake game

Tags: android, eclipse

How do i go to the next text when my snake eat a food? (When the snake eat the food, the text will change from testing to success.) I'm using the snake game provided by eclipse. This is the code i have done so far. I am doing this for my project so i appreciate all the help i can get.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Snake extends Activity {

/**
 * Constants for desired direction of moving the snake
 */
public static int MOVE_LEFT = 0;
public static int MOVE_UP = 1;
public static int MOVE_DOWN = 2;
public static int MOVE_RIGHT = 3;

private static String ICICLE_KEY = "snake-view";

private SnakeView mSnakeView;

/**
 * Called when Activity is first created. Turns off the title bar, sets up the content views,
 * and fires up the SnakeView.
 * 
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.snake_layout);
    init();

    mSnakeView = (SnakeView) findViewById(R.id.snake);
    mSnakeView.setDependentViews((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text),
            findViewById(R.id.arrowContainer), findViewById(R.id.background));

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // We were just launched -- set up a new game
        mSnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.READY);
    } else {
        // We are being restored
        Bundle map = savedInstanceState.getBundle(ICICLE_KEY);
        if (map != null) {
            mSnakeView.restoreState(map);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Store the game state
    outState.putBundle(ICICLE_KEY, mSnakeView.saveState());
}

private int currentQuestion;
private String [] questions;
private TextView questionView;

public void init() {
    questions = new String[]{"testing","success"};
    currentQuestion = -1;
    questionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.QuestionTextView);
    showQuestion();
}
public void showQuestion() {
    currentQuestion++;
    if(currentQuestion == questions.length)
        currentQuestion =0;
    questionView.setText(questions[currentQuestion]);

    } 
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your questions is?

Comment: now i am displaying the text "testing" and i wan it to change to "success" when my snake eat a food

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking out the source code (which I did here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2_r1/com/example/android/snake/SnakeView.java), I dont think it's possible to add this functionality without altering the source code...

However, if u want to edit the source to make it work, I would suggest the following:

create an interface to use as a listener

```
public interface AppleEatenListener{
    public void appleEaten(int size);
}
```

Then add a variable of this interface to the SnakeView class

```
private AppleEatenListener mAppleEatenListener;
```

Create a setter in the SnakeView class to set the mAppleEatenListener

```
public void setAppleEatenListener(AppleEatenListener listener){
    this.mAppleEatenListener = listener;
}
```

After that, make your way down to the updateSnake() method in the SnakeView class and find the following piece of code (consider using ctrl+f (search function)):

**This snippet comes from the current source code:**

```
// except if we want the snake to grow
if (!growSnake) {
    mSnakeTrail.remove(mSnakeTrail.size() - 1);
}
```

And here we want to add, that if the snake should grow, we call the AppleEatenListener's function appleEaten(), like so:

```
 // except if we want the snake to grow
if (!growSnake) {
    mSnakeTrail.remove(mSnakeTrail.size() - 1);
}
else{
    if(mAppleEatenListener != null){
        mAppleEatenListener.appleEaten(mSnakeTrail.size());
    }
}
```

Now, we should return to your own Snake class and add the following in onCreate():

```
mSnakeView.setOnAppleEatenListener(new AppleEatenListener() {
        @Override
        public void appleEaten(int size) {
            showQuestion();
            //size is the current size of the snake after the apple was eaten
        }
    });
```

Note that I've added that the listener requests a "size" parameter, I'm supposing it could be useful to know the size of the snake after it has eaten an apple, since I didn't see a function for requesting the size of the snake in the API either...

I have not tested this code, but I hope this helps u at least a little

Comment: Omg thanks it works! Do you have any ways of contacting you? e.g Skype or something. I would like to ask you some more questions related to this.

Comment: feel free to add me: you can find my skype name on this link (expires in 60 minutes): http://pastebin.com/tvWHjrmD